# Unexpected characters in the end of Arduino char[]

Tags: arduino

I have char[] inside an Arduino sketch. 
Code:

```
int i = 0;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){
  i++;
  Serial.println(i);
  char fff[8] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
  Serial.println(fff);
  delay(200);
}
```

Listening to the port i see:

```
1
00000000²
2
00000000²
3
00000000²
4
00000000²
```

...

How can i fix this problem with unexpected characters at the end of a printable char?

Comment: Isn't it because you string is not null terminated? Have you tried: `char fff[9] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0', 0};`?

Comment: char myword[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fff` string is not null terminated so the `Serial.println()` function doesn't know when to stop reading characters from memory and sending them to the serial port. It stops as soon as it finds the first null byte in memory - leading to unpredictable behavior.

To fix the problem you will need to put a null character on the end of the string (and make sure you have allocated enough memory to cover it). In a character array the null character can be encoded as either a number (`0`) or as a character using an escape sequence (`'\0'`).

Therefore, change the definition of `fff` to:

```
char fff[9] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 0 };
```

or:

```
char fff[9] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '\0' };
```